# Meteor collection in a dedicated file

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6

i've found something strange and I look for explanations.
In my meteor project, I have a file named collections.js which contains:

```
const Interventions = new Mongo.Collection('interventions');
```

(I want to use const to take the habit working with es6)

In my client/interventions.js, I want to get all interventions then I've wrote:

```
Template.interventions.helpers({
  interventions: function () {
    return Interventions.find({});    
  }
});
```

My interventions will never be pulled because of the `const` keyword ? If I remove it, I can get my data.
Can you explain me why please ?

Answer (score 1):

That's because `const` limits scope of `Interventions` variable to `collections.js` file, so `Interventions` is not attached to `window` object, so it's not global and you can't use it in other files.